# Is it Possible to update Postgresql from version 9.2 to 10 on centos

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-10

Updating postgreSql 9.2 to 10 on centos 7, gives me error while executing the pg_upgrade command.

It says cluster was not shutdown cleanely.

I've followed the steps given on Postgresql official site

```
sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install postgresql10-server

sudo systemctl stop postgresql-9.2.service && sudo systemctl stop postgresql-10.service

sudo su postgres
cd ~/
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/
```

Postgresql should be updated to 10, without loss of data

Comment: Please copy/paste the EXACT error message.  Please let us know if this is a standalone Centos 7 server, or a cluster.  If a cluster, please provide additional details.  Finally, you might post your question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) and/or [Centos 7 Community Forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=47)

Comment: bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/data/ --new-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/ --old-bindir /usr/bin/ --new-bindir /usr/pgsql-10/bin/
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

The source cluster was not shut down cleanly.
Failure, exiting

Comment: The exact error message is :- The source cluster was not shut down cleanly.
Failure, exiting

Comment: So you don't have a cluster, correct?  Look [here](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2404041)

Comment: As always when you have problems with a database: read the log file. It will tell you why there was no clean shutdown.

Comment: if it says cluster is not shutdown cleanly, then how can we resolve this issue ?